# Is this Q/A a good fit for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I just found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57155654/5768908) on the "Hot Network Questions" list. I was initially afraid of linking it because of the meta effect, but there is no way to discuss it unless linking it (and it's showing up on "Hot Questions" anyway...)

It seems to me the kind of Q/A that you could find in the dark ages of Stack Overflow, upvotes and all. It asks about installing a software, and the most upvoted answer is the proverbial *"turn it off and turn it on again"*. That being said, it seems a good question for Super User.

Now comes my question: the linked Q/A has more than 2300 views, but not a single close vote (or a downvote either, for that matter). I was about to close-vote as off topic, but then I thought *"if 2300 users saw nothing wrong, probably there is nothing wrong"*. What am I missing here?

Comment: _The most upvoted answer is the proverbial "turn it off and turn it on again". That being said, it seems a good question for Super User._ You are going on the wrong side. Question need to on topic. On-topic/Off-topc should not be selected by answers.

Comment: That was just an *additional* information. The main issue here remains the question itself, which in my opinion is off topic. However, according to the answers (which I accepted), questions about installing software are on topic. Therefore, the case is closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**What topics can I ask about here?**

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
>   who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow
>   questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question
>   generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - ***software tools commonly used by programmers***; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software    development

*Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:*

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic
>   for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily
>   for programming.

As @Makoto said, Xcode is a tool developers use and tools that developers use are in scope which should not be considered as off-topic. Apart from it, this question has high ranked answers which are valuable to the community.

Answer (score 6):

There is a nonzero chance that someone will experience this with Xcode, and the answers can demonstrate themselves to be actually useful to anyone going through this.

That's all you have to look at, really; Xcode is a tool developers use and tools that developers use are in scope.

It's *fine*.

Comment: *"tools that developers use are in scope"*... Mmmm, I'm not sure. You can use your same reasoning for almost every software developers use. So, according to this reasoning, questions about installing them would be on-topic at Stack Overflow?

Comment: Honestly - I'm not a Mac guy, but I'd believe that problems with Xcode are largely tolerated here, and again - nonzero chance that someone else will have this problem. What value would removing or closing it serve?

Comment: Value? none. But it's still off topic nonetheless. So, they (SO) should change the guidelines for close-voting.

Comment: Fine; cast a close vote on it if you're so inclined. I'm only expressing the opinion that I don't see it as an off-topic question, and I actually see value in the answers too, so closing it accomplishes nothing in my eyes.

Comment: I stand corrected: the [other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387572/5768908) just provided the reference showing that it's not off topic.

Comment: ... wait... You haven't seen the on-topic help page before? That's what the other answer is quoting, verbatim (emphasis theirs).

Comment: Yes, I did, years ago... but I probably forgot that passage about *software tools*, and I was under the impression that questions about installing them would be fit for Super User. My bad.