# Where is the right place to ask questions about Xdebug?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Xdebug is a debugging tool.

But should I ask about it on Stack Overflow or on Super User?

Comment: What question would you like to ask?

Comment: Examples of good xdebug questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bxdebug%5D+is%3Aq+closed%3A0+hasaccepted%3Ayes+created%3A2018..&mixed=0

Comment: I want to ask how to use the xdebug debugger

Comment: Probably too broad if that's the entirety of your question.

Comment: How to use xdebug seems a rather broad question. If you have trouble installing the tool in the first place super user might be appropriate. After that I would pick a debug scenario, something like, how do I inspect the call stack in another thread.

Comment: I don't mean xdebug itself, but the xdebug client https://github.com/michael-vostrikov/XDebugClient

Comment: Either way if your question is simply how do I use it, it's likely to be too broad

Comment: You should first be clear exactly about what you are asking the question. It seems you have (broad) questions regarding the use of a specific Xdebug Client, not about the Xdebug extension.

Comment: Its not a broad question, I just want to know where I can find instructions on how to use it.

Comment: Then it's a question asking about offsite resources. "Where can I find a book or tutorial" it's a specific kind of close reason

Answer (score -8):

Why don't use to ask it on Stack Overflow?

According to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic,

**software tools commonly used by programmers; and is** on topic.

Comment: In general , yes. But when you have an install issue, I wouldn't put my bets on SO.

Comment: I have a question about the usage of the xdebug client

Comment: @rene Are they offtopic? I have seen so many installation errors, issues on SO...

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson well, having seen many questions that ask X doesn't make X on-topic. If the installation problem boils down to a basic lack of knowledge how to setup anything at all, I do think Super User is the better venue. I would say that questions about *software tools that are already installed and running* are on topic but YMMV.

Comment: Also if your question is reporting a bug on xdebug you'll likely want to be doing that on some xdebug site rather than here, although you might get suggestions as to how to avoid the bug here.

Comment: And if your question is where is the user guide, installation instructions etc that's asking for offsite resources which is off topic

Comment: @rene and Robert Longson, that's exactly what I thought: installation issues would be off topic. However, this question of mine showed me that I was wrong: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/387569/5768908. Both answers argue it is indeed on topic...

Comment: That question has a very specific issue though, and an error message to go with it. It also provides a bit more context than *"how do I use/install X"* or *"where are instructions for X"*. IMO it's not really comparable.